# D3 treemaps with images

Tags: d3.js, treemap

Can someone show me how to place images into a d3 tree map.
Eventually I’d like to nest 3 hierarchies, but for now I just need  simple ‘flat’ tree map with about 20 images

Answer (score 0):

I forked [Mike's](https://beta.observablehq.com/@mbostock/d3-treemap) example and created a tree map with images.  You can find it [here](https://beta.observablehq.com/@umeshmaharshi30/d3-treemap)

I am using [this](https://bl.ocks.org/ganezasan/52fced34d2182483995f0ca3960fe228) as base and added comments.

Hope this helps

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 960px;
}
form {
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
}
.node {
  border: solid 1px white;
  font: 10px sans-serif;
  line-height: 12px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  text-indent: 2px;
}
</style>
<form>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="size" checked> Size</label>
  <label><input type="radio" name="mode" value="count"> Count</label>
</form>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<script>
'use strict';

const margin = {top: 40, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
      width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
      color = d3.scaleOrdinal().range(d3.schemeCategory20c);

const treemap = d3.treemap().size([width, height]);

const div = d3.select("body").append("div")
    .style("position", "relative")
    .style("width", (width + margin.left + margin.right) + "px")
    .style("height", (height + margin.top + margin.bottom) + "px")
    .style("left", margin.left + "px")
    .style("top", margin.top + "px");
 
 // this is the key, the data has to hierarchical with size or value attribute over which the tree will be created
   var data = {
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "parent 1",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "child 1 parent 1",
  "size" : 2
    },
    {
     "name": "child 2 parent 1",
  "size" : 8
    }]
 },
 {
   "name": "parent 2",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "child 1 parent 2",
  "size" : 9
    },
    {
     "name": "child 2 parent 2",
  "size" : 8
    }]
 }
]
};
 // this creates the actual tree object with size of each element based on the size value(based on cumulative size of its children)
  const root = d3.hierarchy(data, (d) => d.children)
    .sum((d) => d.size);

  const tree = treemap(root);
  
  
 // appending a div for element in the root and setting size based on the data 
  const node = div.datum(root).selectAll(".node")
      .data(tree.leaves())
    .enter().append("div")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .style("left", (d) => d.x0 + "px")
      .style("top", (d) => d.y0 + "px")
      .style("width", (d) => Math.max(0, d.x1 - d.x0 - 1) + "px")
      .style("height", (d) => Math.max(0, d.y1 - d.y0  - 1) + "px")
      .style("background", (d) => color(d.parent.data.name))
      .text((d) => d.data.name);

  d3.selectAll("input").on("change", function change() {
    const value = this.value === "count"
        ? (d) => { return d.size ? 1 : 0;}
        : (d) => { return d.size; };

    const newRoot = d3.hierarchy(data, (d) => d.children)
      .sum(value);

    node.data(treemap(newRoot).leaves())
      .transition()
        .duration(1500)
        .style("left", (d) => d.x0 + "px")
        .style("top", (d) => d.y0 + "px")
        .style("width", (d) => Math.max(0, d.x1 - d.x0 - 1) + "px")
        .style("height", (d) => Math.max(0, d.y1 - d.y0  - 1) + "px")
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Thank you , but the code you sent was way too difficult for me. I am just beginning at this and  was hoping for something MUCH simpler- Just maybe 16-20 images- with only a single hierarchy (for now).

Ideally to been, I want to just build a treetop with 20 images and be able to click on any of them and zoom that image to the root size.

I want to use the treetop layout here because I eventually plan to have at least another level of nested levels and also be about to alter the data on the fly with cool transitions